# Internal DNS Server's Interactions with Local Client Computers... How do they work?

Tags: ubuntu, router, bind, internal-dns, split-dns

I'm setting up [Split Horizon DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS). I have an internal DNS server, running Ubuntu Server 10.04. Everything has been set up properly as per [this article's](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Split_DNS) instructions. (I know that it is a mail server but I figured this may be a good starting point since their instructions are complete)

---

On my local DNS server,

dig *mywebsite.com*

returns the proper IP address to the DNS server.

---

Now, on my Windows PC, if I

ping *mywebsite.com*

it says that it `... could not find host...`

---

Under `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties` the option `Obtain DNS server addresses automatically` is checked. `D-Link DIR-632` is my router and is also acting as a DHCP server. I assume that the reason why the `ping` is not working is because the request isn't hitting the DNS server.

My question is, what do I have to do to make sure that the client computers all use the local DNS server addresses for domain names configured on the local DNS server?

Comment: Have you configured the DHCP service to hand out the correct DNS server address? On the Windows client what do you get when you do an `ipconfig /all`? Does it show the correct DNS server address?

Comment: No I haven't and no it doesn't. I'm now trying to find the DNS settings within the routers DHCP section... I don't see anything in the DHCP settings to hand out the correct DNS server address. The only DNS setting I've found so far is DNS relay. Should I just set up the DNS server with DHCP on it and manage everything from there?

Comment: @user29600: That would be the preferred method. The DNS service on most SOHO routers is intended for the average user that doesn't have the "advanced" needs that you do regarding DNS, meaning they're intended for environments that don't have their own DNS server. As such, the DNS service on most SOHO routers are DNS forwarders/resolvers and not fully functioning DNS servers and do not host any DNS zones nor do they participate in any DNS split horizon configuration that you might set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your DHCP server to hand out the IP address of your DNS server as *the* DNS server in DHCP requests.  Doing that on your little router may or may not be possible; if it isn't (or, honestly, even if it is) I'd turn the DHCP server off on your router and run a real DHCP server off your DNS server, it's far more flexible.

Comment: Going to set up a DHCP server and see if I can get it working.